# Synchronization of two project editions

Tags: synchronization, open-source, gitlab

There is software distribution type, when one version is opensource and other is enterprise version.
Enterprise version is proprietary, but based on opensource version of software.
For example, [GitLab CE and GitLab EE](https://gitlab.com)

I suppose, that would be just two git (or other VCS) repositories, and developers doing one way merge every time: opensource to EE + unique commits to EE, but not sure..

How to do this right, better?

Answer (score 2):

> developers doing one way merge every time

That would be the idea:

- in the EE cloned repo, developers can add a remote to the opensource CE GitLab repo:

  ```
   git remote add oss /url/public/gitlab/repo
  ```
- At any time, they can fetch and merge:

  ```
   git fetch oss
   git merge oss/master
  ```

Ideally, if a developer is the only one working on a branch, they could rebase said branch on top of oss/master, and then force push.
But if they are several ones working on the same branch of the proprietary repo, a merge is safer.